# Do I need to change my residence status [Non-EU citizen working in Poland]

Tags: student-visa, blue-card, students, residence-cards, poland

I am an Indian citizen living and working in Poland as a Skilled Migrant worker. I currently work with a bulge bracket bank and have held the EU Blue-Card(Karta Pobytu) for more than 2 years.

My spouse had applied for a blue-card on the basis of her being my dependent. She now has full-time employment in Poland and signed an indefinite period contract with her employer again in the banking sector.

Both our blue cards (temporary residence permit) expire in June, 2023. I have already applied for the renewal of the permit. My spouse plans to apply independently for her EU-Blue card on the basis of her permanent contract for work.

I am contemplating leaving my full-time employment and enrolling for a Masters in Applied Mathematics at the university in my city, in October 2023. I have a couple of questions on this, and any tips/suggestions would be incredibly insightful.

1. Do I need to apply for a student visa before I can study at a Polish university? Or do I need to inform the immigration authorities (voivodeship) for a change of the purpose of residing in Poland in my Karta Pobytu application and try to obtain a Student Temporary Residence Card?
2. Would my spouse' employment be affected as a result of me leaving my permanent employment?

I am also considering soliciting advice from an immigration lawyer, but any insights here would ultimately help.